# Replacing an instrumentation amp with an op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I want to join a Load Cell (LoadMaster SPL 149 80) with arduino uno. Whenever I search online, I find INA 125p amplifier in the circuit but I want to know if there is an alternative to INA 125p amplifier? Can I build an op-amp based voltage gain circuit for the same function? The Load cell works on the range 0-9V.  Please guide.

Comment: The INA125 is a combined in-amp and voltage reference. You can of course do without it, but you would need at least two opamps, a set of precision matched resistors, and an alternative voltage reference to replace it. It would help to know why you do not want to use the INA125: as far as I can see it is not particularly expensive and has adequate specifications for the application.

Answer (score 1):

The key word here to search for is "Instrumentation Amplifier". These have several important characteristics for use amplifying a load cell: Low offset voltage, low bias current, and high common-mode voltage range. They also have gain settable via a single external resistor.

You could theoretically find a regular opamp with those properties and build a differential input amplifier circuit, but you'd have to buffer the input signals to get low input impedance, and any mismatch in your components would contribute to error. In practice, it's much easier to use a premade instrumentation amp. INA125 is one such, but there are many alternatives.